# Confused on SELECT 1 FROM

Tags: mysql, sql, select

If I do the following query:
`SELECT 1 FROM emp;`

I get:

```
mysql> SELECT 1 FROM emp;  
+---+  
| 1 |  
+---+  
| 1 |  
| 1 |  
| 1 |  
| 1 |  
| 1 |  
| 1 |  
| 1 |  
| 1 |  
| 1 |  
| 1 |  
| 1 |  
| 1 |  
| 1 |  
| 1 |  
| 1 |  
+---+
```

If I do:

`SELECT 1 FROM emp e WHERE 20=e.deptno;`  I get:

```
mysql> SELECT 1 FROM emp e WHERE 20=e.deptno;  
+---+  
| 1 |   
+---+  
| 1 |  
| 1 |   
| 1 |   
| 1 |   
| 1 |   
| 1 |    
+---+  
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And if I do:

```
mysql> SELECT deptno FROM emp;  
+--------+  
| deptno |  
+--------+  
|     10 |   
|     10 |   
|     10 |   
|     20 |   
|     20 |   
|     20 |   
|     20 |   
|     20 |   
|     20 |  
|     30 |  
|     30 |  
|     30 |  
|     30 |  
|     30 |  
|    100 |  
+--------+  
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I see that there are 6 rows with `20` and 6 rows in the previous:  `SELECT 1 FROM emp e WHERE 20=e.deptno;`

But how are these queries related?

Comment: I don't actually think this question should be closed. Yes, it shows a lack of knowledge about how an SQL select works, but its hardly too localized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you select the `deptno` and a literal value, like this:

```
SELECT 1, deptno FROM emp
```

you get:

```
1   10
1   10
1   10
1   20
1   20
1   20
1   20
1   20
1   20
1   30
1   30
1   30
1   30
1   30
1  100
```

If you filter out only the `deptno` 20, like this:

```
SELECT 1, deptno FROM emp where deptno = 20
```

you get this subset of the previous query:

```
1   20
1   20
1   20
1   20
1   20
1   20
```

If you leave out the `deptno` from the result:

```
SELECT 1 FROM emp where deptno = 20
```

you get only the ones:

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 1 FROM emp e WHERE 20=e.deptno;
```

Query selects the number of rows based on your `where` condition but you are not selecting any column value instead of just selecting `1` that's why it's showing 6 rows having `1`

Answer (score 3):

There are six rows with `20 = e.deptno`, therefore you get six `1`s in the second query (the seventh `1` on top is just an auto-generated column name).